# Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting web_1 | TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

Hello I occured an error like in title during composing Django web app. I get this error

```
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have no idea how can i solve it, I have already, restarted Postgresql database and docker but I neither of these work.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'fitshop',
        'USER': 'fitshopuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'fitpass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
   

    services:
      db:
        image: postgres
        volumes:
          - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
          - POSTGRES_USER=fitshopuser
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
      web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
          - .:/code
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
          - db
```

Comment: Your database server does not run on "localhost".

Comment: Note that ``0.0.0.0`` is all *IPv4* addresses while ``::1`` is an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 3):

When running in docker you could use the service name as the hostname. So, your  Django database settings would be like this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'fitshopuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

The values in the settings should be equal to the environment variables provided in docker-compose file for `db`

```yaml
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_DB=postgres          # NAME
          - POSTGRES_USER=fitshopuser     # USER
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres    # PASSWORD
```

As per your docker configuration for Postgres, docker initializes a database named `postgres` with username as `fitshopuser`, password as `postgres` and hostname as `db` on port `5432`.
Should be using these values in Django settings.

About the error:

> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
> web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

with `depends_on` in service named `web` it only checks the service `db` is running or not. It does not mean that the Postgres database is up and running.

You can find about this in the official docker documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

```yaml
        depends_on:
          - db
```

Inorder to check if check if Postgres is ready and is accepting connections over port 5432, use scripts like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)

OR

I would simple install `postgresql-client` in service named `web` and using the command `pg_isready` check if Postgres is ready.

Add these lines to the dockerfile.

```
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client

# provide permissions to run the entrypoint script (update path accordingly)
RUN chmod +x /path/to/entrypoint.sh
```

Update/Add entrypoint.sh file.

```sh
# entrypoint.sh
while ! pg_isready -h db -p 5432 --username=fitshopuser ; do
    echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
    sleep 2
done
```

Specify the entrypoint to service named `web`.

```yaml
      web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
          - .:/code
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        entrypoint: "/path/to/entrypoint.sh"   # Update path
        depends_on:
          - db
```

Comment: It does not work, even when I do not want to use docker, just write "python manage.py runserver" i get the same error.

Comment: The error that you provided says that the Postgres database is not ready yet and is not accepting connections. Potgres docker takes a little bit of time to configure its database and to start accepting connections over port 5432.

Comment: @Kay check if the Postgres is up and running and is accepting connections over port 5432.